# Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ‘rstatix’

Tags: r, rgui

I'm trying to use fviz_pca_ind, but I get the following error

```
> fviz_pca_ind(res.Fr_Temp)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rstatix’
>
```

I tried to install rstatix

```
install.packages("rstatix")
```

But I got this :

```
> install.packages("rstatix")
Installation du package dans ‘C:/Users/Mouad AITALI/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)
--- SVP sélectionner un miroir CRAN pour cette session ---

  Une version binaire est disponible mais la version du source est plus
  récente:
        binary source needs_compilation
rstatix  0.6.0  0.7.0             FALSE

installation du package source ‘rstatix’

essai de l'URL 'https://mirror.marwan.ma/cran/src/contrib/rstatix_0.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 402481 bytes (393 KB)
downloaded 393 KB

* installing *source* package 'rstatix' ...
** package 'rstatix' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'Rcpp'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Exécution arrêtée
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rstatix'
* removing 'C:/Users/Mouad AITALI/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstatix'

Les packages source téléchargés sont dans
        ‘C:\Users\Mouad AITALI\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0m04WG\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rstatix") :
  l'installation du package ‘rstatix’ a eu un statut de sortie non nul
>
```

Comment: Please show the complete output of `install.packages("rstatix")`. The actual error message is usually included before that final warning message.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for your comment, I've updated my question

Comment: When it asked you to build the package from sources, just say “no”. The binary version would probably be fine. Or else install the package Rcpp separately before installing this one.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you so much, it worked after I install the rcpp

Comment: if this solves your problem, you are encouraged to post your own answer (or @MrFlick could post an answer, or we could try to find a duplicate)